# 自分自身のサイズをオフセットに渡したい

Tags: swift, ios, swiftui

モーダル的に振る舞うボトムシートを作成しています。
ボトムシートを開くときと閉じるときはアニメーションしたいです。
下記のようにオフセットを使ったコードを書きました。
このオフセットに自分自身のViewのサイズを渡せるとちょうどいい具合の位置に引っ込んで見えなくなると思うのですが、取得方法はわかるのですが、オフセットに渡す良い方法がわかりません。（ということで現在は適当に大きな値として`500`を与えています）なにか良い方法はありますか？

（自分自身のサイズと言っていますが、SwiftUIのモディファイアは新しいViewを入れ子にしていくようなイメージ？なので、本来は自分自身という表現は違うような気もするのですが、良い言葉がわかりません。コードコメント箇所を見ていただけると、やりたいことは伝わると思っています。）

コード：

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var isShow = false

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Button(
        "Show Sheet",
        action: {
          withAnimation {
            self.isShow.toggle()
          }
        }
      )
      .zIndex(0)
      .allowsHitTesting(!isShow)

      BottomSheet(
        isShow: self.$isShow,
        content: {
          VStack {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
          }
          .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity
          )
          .background(Color(.yellow))
        }
      )
      .zIndex(1)
    }
  }
}

struct ScrimView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {}.frame(
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      maxHeight: .infinity,
      alignment: .bottom
    )
    .background(
      Color(.gray)
    )
  }
}

struct BottomSheet<Content: View>: View {
  private let content: () -> Content
  @Binding var isShow: Bool

  init(
    isShow: Binding<Bool>,
    content: @escaping () -> Content
  ) {
    self._isShow = isShow
    self.content = content
  }

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      ScrimView().zIndex(
        0
      )
      .opacity(
        self.isShow ? 0.5 : 0
      )

      VStack {
        Button(
          "X",
          action: {
            withAnimation {
              self.isShow = false
            }
          }
        )
        self.content()
      }
      .zIndex(1)
      .background(Color(.white))
      .cornerRadius(10)
      .offset(
        x: 0,
        y: self.isShow ? 0 : 500 // <-- 取得した高さを指定したい
      ).background(
        GeometryReader { g in
          let _ = print(g.size.height) // <-- ここで高さを取得できる
          Color(.clear)
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

メイン側コード：

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FooApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

ほとんど、関係ないと思いますが、制作過程で行った別の質問も念の為参考として記載しておきます。
[ios - How to prevent the ZStack lower level View from reacting? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68573525/how-to-prevent-the-zstack-lower-level-view-from-reacting)

この質問を書いたあとに別アプローチとして下記の質問もしたので、念の為追記しておきます。
[ios - Why isn't one of the animations active? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577762/why-isnt-one-of-the-animations-active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サイズを取得して与えることは下記を参考にすることでできました。

[SwiftUI - Get size of child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573373/swiftui-get-size-of-child)

全体のコード：

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var isShow = false

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Button(
        "Show Sheet",
        action: {
          withAnimation {
            self.isShow.toggle()
          }
        }
      )
      .zIndex(0)
      .allowsHitTesting(!isShow)

      BottomSheet(
        isShow: self.$isShow,
        content: {
          VStack {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
          }
          .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity
          )
          .background(Color(.yellow))
        }
      )
      .zIndex(1)
    }
  }
}

struct ScrimView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {}.frame(
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      maxHeight: .infinity,
      alignment: .bottom
    )
    .background(
      Color(.gray)
    )
  }
}

struct BottomSheet<Content: View>: View {
  private let content: () -> Content
  @Binding var isShow: Bool
  @State var size: CGSize = .zero

  init(
    isShow: Binding<Bool>,
    content: @escaping () -> Content
  ) {
    self._isShow = isShow
    self.content = content
  }

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      ScrimView().zIndex(
        0
      )
      .opacity(
        self.isShow ? 0.5 : 0
      )

      ChildSizeReader(size: $size) {
        VStack {
          Button(
            "X",
            action: {
              withAnimation {
                self.isShow = false
              }
            }
          )
          self.content()
        }
        .zIndex(1)
        .background(Color(.white))
        .cornerRadius(10)
      }
      .offset(
        x: 0,
        y: self.isShow ? 0 : size.height
      )
    }
  }
}

struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {
  @Binding var size: CGSize

  let content: () -> Content
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      content().background(
        GeometryReader { proxy in
          Color.clear.preference(
            key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
            value: proxy.size
          )
        }
      )
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
      self.size = preferences
    }
  }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  typealias Value = CGSize
  static var defaultValue: Value = .zero

  static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
    _ = nextValue()
  }
}
```

ただ、セーフエリアの下側を考慮できていなかったのか、オフセットの距離は足りなかったようです。